# In a ReHosted WfDesigner why I cant get the activities within it ? And how to get the current Activity?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, workflow-rehosting

I am working with a rehosted workflow designer. In my C# code I do have access to the instance of the WorkflowDesigner.  How do I get access to the current activity that I am at (the cursor is at ) or I have just opened it. 
This is the  workflow I am referring to:

```
System.Activities.Presentation.WorkflowDesigner x;
```

How do I access the current  activity or all activities within the x.

[image: The image of a Sequence parent and its two childs]

I have tried this as well:

```
 ModelService modelService = x.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>();
 Activity a = modelService.Root.GetCurrentValue() as Activity;
 IEnumerable <Activity> MyActivities = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(a );
```

when I run this code there is NO activities returned within the root "a" in other words myActivities IEnumerable is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on how to get the selected activity
    Selection sel = x.Context.Items.GetValue();